# Split the String involving two special character

Tags: java

I have a string value which look like the following :

```
TE\;R20\;T11\;19
```

which i would like to split it into `TE`,`R20`,`T11` and `19`. I try to apply the `split` method on it but unfortunately it's still can't split the string properly

Here is my source code

```
String description1 = CSVdata2[7];
System.out.println("The description1 is :"+description1);
String email1 = CSVdata2[2];
String [] data1 = description1.split(";");
String ID1 = data1[0];
String [] data2 = SysID1.split("/");
String ID2 = data2[0];
System.out.println("The ID2 is :"+ID2);
```

Here is my sample output

```
The description1 is :TE\;R20\;T11\;19
The ID2 is :TE\
```

I tried search some approach online but i still can't make it split into the string that i want

Comment: `String[] parts = inputString.split("\\\\;");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` because in String `\` is an escape character. Try below code:

```
    String s = "TE\\;R20\\;T11\\;19";
String arr[] = s.split("\\\\;");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

To escape `\` you need to use `\`

**OP:**

```
[TE, R20, T11, 19]
```

Comment: i cant change my string to TE\\;R20\\;T11\\;19

Comment: @yumi You don't have to convert. In Java single \ is not allowed in `String`. So, in your code `description1` already contains `"TE\\;R20\\;T11\\;19"`. Just use `description1.split("\\\\;");`

Comment: haha, i guess i miss understood your meaning. Because i m not sure how java treat "\\" and "\"

Answer (score 1):

```
    String test = "TE\\;R20\\;T11\\;19";
    System.out.println(test);
    for(String sub : test.split("\\\\;"))
    {
        System.out.println(sub);
    }
```

output is:
TE\;R20\;T11\;19
TE
R20
T11
19

My simple code. The String.split method accepts a regex string rather than a single character to split.

Comment: i cant change my string into TE\\;R20\\;T11\\;19. Only allow "\", not "\\"

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name="TE\\;R20\\;T11\\;19";
    String a[]=name.split("\\\\;");
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**By using `"Pattern.quote"` we can split** *string*

```
String separator = "\\;";
String value = "TE\\;R20\\;T11\\;19";
String[] arrValues = value.split(Pattern.quote(separator));

 System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arrValues));
```

Output :

> [TE, R20, T11, 19]